# Is valid to use header twice to build nav?

Tags: html, css

as mozilla said https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header. and my design have logo in middle. is it right i do it like this? the reason i have 2 header, cause logo position will change in desktop mode to first. menu to 2nd position. search still same.

```css
.container {
  width: 320px;
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
}

.container>div>nav,
header {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <nav>menu</nav>
    <header>logo</header>
    <header>search</header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest way to figure out if something is officially allowed is to use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). If the Validator finds issues then it is not allowed by W3 specifications. If the validator has no issues then you're obviosly good to use it.

Comment: @tacoshy, that's not exactly true. It's like saying "if it's legal it's ok". Yeah, nah. I doubt that the W3C validator is also a comprehensive accessibility tool. Semantics is a complex thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but this is a matter of opinion. What's "right" varies by philosophy. You can have more than one header, but using them stacked simply for layout could be an accessibility fail. I'd move the header element outward and replace with divs.

```css
.container {
  width: 320px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

header>div,
header>nav {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>menu</nav>
    <div>logo</div>
    <div>search</div>
  </header>
</div>
```